# VerifiedMonad instance for an error monad

Tags: idris

I'm trying to complete the `monadLeftIdentity` proof for the following data type:

```
data ErrorM : (a : Type) -> Type where
  AllGood : a -> ErrorM a
  Error : String -> ErrorM a

instance Monad ErrorM where
  (AllGood x) >>= f = f x
  (Error err) >>= f = Error err

instance VerifiedMonad ErrorM where
  monadApplicative (AllGood f) (AllGood x) = Refl
  monadApplicative (Error err) (AllGood x) = Refl
  monadApplicative (AllGood f) (Error err) = Refl
  monadApplicative (Error er1) (Error er2) = Refl
  monadLeftIdentity x f = ?z
```

I've left out the instances for `Functor`, `Applicative` and their `Verified` counterparts, as they're quite verbose and trivial. Do let me know, can paste them all here.

I've tried to rewrite `return x` as `pure x` or `AllGood x`, but have been unsuccessful in doing so (the rewrite does nothing to the proof state).

I've also tried to refine `return x` like so:

```
  monadLeftIdentity x f with (return x)
    monadLeftIdentity x' f | AllGood x' = ?z
```

but I get the following err msg:

```
 `-- Error.idr line 51 col 22:
     When elaborating left hand side of with block in Prelude.Monad.Astra.Error.ErrorM instance of Prelude.Monad.VerifiedMonad, method monadLeftIdentity:
     Can't match on with block in Prelude.Monad.Astra.Error.ErrorM instance of Prelude.Monad.VerifiedMonad, method monadLeftIdentity a (AllGood x') x' b f return
```

How does one go about this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems like a bug in the Idris typechecker that doesn't resolve overloaded functions even when they are completely determined by the type.

To witness, I can make a proof like this:

```
myLeftIdentity : (x : a) -> (f : a -> ErrorM b) -> return x >>= f = f x
myLeftIdentity x f = Refl
```

and it typechecks just fine, but it can't be used as a witness in the instance:

```
instance VerifiedMonad ErrorM where
  monadApplicative (AllGood _) (AllGood _) = Refl
  monadApplicative (Error _) _ = Refl
  monadApplicative (AllGood _) (Error _) = Refl

  monadLeftIdentity = myLeftIdentity
```

results in

```
 Can't unify
         (x : a) -> (f : a -> ErrorM b) -> return x >>= f = f x
 with
         (x : a) -> (f : a -> ErrorM b) -> Main.ErrorM instance of Prelude.Monad.Monad, method >>= (return x) f = f x
```

even though the two `>>=` should be one and the same.

Interestingly, I was able to work around this by defining my own version of the `Monad` and `VerifiedMonad` classes:

```
infixl 5 >>=>

class Applicative m => Monad' (m : Type -> Type) where
  (>>=>) : m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b

return' : Monad' m => a -> m a
return' = pure

instance Monad' ErrorM where
  (AllGood x) >>=> f = f x
  (Error err) >>=> f = Error err

class (Monad' m, VerifiedApplicative m) => VerifiedMonad' (m : Type -> Type) where
  monadLeftIdentity : (x : a) -> (f : a -> m b) -> return' x >>=> f = f x

instance VerifiedMonad' ErrorM where
  monadLeftIdentity x f = Refl
```

Comment: I've filed it as https://github.com/idris-lang/Idris-dev/issues/1913 with the Idris devs